# Hibernate polymorphic collection mapping with annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, mapping, polymorphism

I have an Abstract class for my clients:

```
@Entity
public class AbstractClientEntity extends AbstractPersonneEntity implements Demarchable {

@Column(name="ID_REFERENT")
private AbstractEmployeEntity referent;
...
```

The concrete class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(TypePersonne.Values.INVITE)
public class InviteEntity extends AbstractClientEntity implements Invitable {
...
```

and

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(TypePersonne.Values.AUTRE)
public class AutreClientEntity extends AbstractClientEntity {
```

and I have an other abstract class for my employee who have a Set of AbstractClientEntity:

```
@Entity
public class AbstractEmployeEntity extends AbstractPersonneEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_REFERENT", nullable = false)
private MonitriceEntity monitrice = new MonitriceEntity();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "referent")
private Set<AbstractClientEntity> listeClients = new HashSet<AbstractClientEntity>();
...
```

The problem is when I trie to run my web-app, this exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/tupper-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractEmployeEntity, at table: PERSONNE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ID_REFERENT)]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:767)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:685)
```

I don't know how I can resolve this problem...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I will answer my own question and hope it will help somebody...

After many tries, I adopt the solution to have a list for each concrete class I have to manage in my AbstractEmployeEntity:

```
@Entity
public class AbstractEmployeEntity extends AbstractPersonneEntity {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "referent")
private Set<HotesseEntity> listeHotesse = new HashSet<HotesseEntity>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "referent")
private Set<InviteEntity> listeInvites = new HashSet<InviteEntity>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "referent")
private Set<AutreClientEntity> listeAutreClients = new HashSet<AutreClientEntity>();
```

Hope this will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

The cause is clear:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractEmployeEntity, at table: PERSONNE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ID_REFERENT)]
```

Your class `ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractEmployeEntity` is not finding column `ID_REFERENT` in your table `PERSONNE`.

How did you map your `AbstractEmployeEntity` class. If it's an abstract class, why not map it with `@MappedSuperclass`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
I swear that the field ID_REFERENT is in my table PERSONNE.
I did map my abstract class with @MappedSuperclass because I want to be able to have a collection of AbstractClientEntity in my AbstractEmployeEntity.

When I trie with the @ MappedSuperclass annotation, the exception 
    org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @ OneToMany or @ ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractEmployeEntity.listeClients[ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractClientEntity]
Is thrown...

Comment: I suggest that you only annotate `@MappedSuperclass` **only** to abstract classes an not concrete classes.

Comment: I tried to annotate all my abstract classes with `@MappedSuperClass` but now I have the similar exception as above but on one concrete class:
nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AmbassadriceEntity.listeClients[ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractClientEntity]